# C++ Subclassing STL streams

Tags: c++, stream, multiple-inheritance

I'm currently trying to write a C++ library to read/write CSV from/to an abstract source/destination of data (string, file, socket, etc). And before you ask, yes, I want to reinvent the wheel.

What I have done so far, without really thinking about it first, is subclassing the `ifstream` and `ofstream` classes so that I can override the behaviour of `operator >>`/`operator <<` to read/write records from/to a CSV file, and combine both of these two subclasses into another class capable of both reading and writing, just like `fstream`, as defined below :

```
template< typename char_type >
class basic_csv_ifstream : public std::basic_ifstream< char_type >
{
public:
    basic_csv_ifstream( const char * path, char_type delim = char_type( ',' ), char_type quote = char_type( '"' ) ) throw();
    basic_csv_ifstream( char_type delim = char_type( ',' ), char_type quote = char_type( '"' ) ) throw();
    basic_csv_ifstream & operator >> ( std::vector< std::basic_string< char_type > > & row );
};

template< typename char_type >
class basic_csv_ofstream : public std::basic_ofstream< char_type >
{
public:
    basic_csv_ofstream( const char * path, char_type delim = char_type( ',' ), char_type quote = char_type( '"' ) ) throw();
    basic_csv_ofstream( char_type delim = char_type( ',' ), char_type quote = char_type( '"' ) ) throw();
    basic_csv_ofstream & operator << ( const std::vector< std::basic_string< char_type > > & row );
};

template< typename char_type >
class basic_csv_fstream : public basic_csv_ifstream< char_type >, public basic_csv_ofstream< char_type >
{
public:
    basic_csv_fstream( const char * path, char_type delim = char_type( ',' ), char_type quote = char_type( '"' ) ) throw();
    basic_csv_fstream( char_type delim = char_type( ',' ), char_type quote = char_type( '"' ) ) throw();
    basic_csv_fstream & operator << ( std::vector< std::basic_string< char_type > > & row );
};

typedef basic_csv_ifstream< char > csv_ifstream;
typedef basic_csv_ofstream< char > csv_ofstream;
typedef basic_csv_fstream< char > csv_fstream;
typedef basic_csv_ifstream< wchar_t > csv_wifstream;
typedef basic_csv_ofstream< wchar_t > csv_wofstream;
typedef basic_csv_fstream< wchar_t > csv_wfstream;
```

But now that I think about it, it seems wrong.

Isn't the main purpose of the class hierarchy of streams provided by the STL to make an abstraction layer for the source/destination of the input/output data ?

Wouldn't it be more correct to write some kind of "stream reader" and "stream writer" classes that would not **be** streams, but instead **have** a (referenced) stream to read/write from/to ?

And a final question is about my class `basic_csv_fstream`. Isn't it incorrect to inherit from both `ifstream` and `ofstream` ? I assume I can't open a same file twice if I open it once with ios_base::out and once with ios_base::out simultaneously.

Comment: `STL` is nothing to do with *streams*, that's about *containers* and *algorithms*.

Comment: @Galik How do you call the library that streams come with ? "standard C++ library" ? "std" ? Correct me if I'm wrong, but these stream classes are (actually) templates, standard and from a library.

Comment: `STL` was the name for a specific set of libraries from the 1990's. It is still often used to refer to the Standard library classes that derived from the `STL`. It's best to do as Galik says and leave the term STL to the descendants  of `STL` to prevent confusion.

Comment: To answer the rest, the c++ Standard refers to the streams as a part of the "Input/output library" (see section  **[input.output]**). "iostreams" is probably as good a  name as any.

Comment: And, with respect to the actual question, I believe the common wisdom to prefer composition over inheritance holds.